# 'The Online Service is not available' Issue in Visual Studio Professional 2013 with Update 5

Tags: windows, visual-studio, azure-devops, ide

I have worked in vscode 2013 until today. But when I'm trying to open my IDE in today morning, it gets 'Your license has gone stale and must be update' error message as following.

[image]

and after I tried to update license and sign In operations. when I'm trying to these two it gets 'The Online service is not available. Please try again later' error message as following.

[image]

I'm using windows operating system.
Is anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 35):

Try this; it worked for me. Just add two `DWORD` values to the Windows Registry. Site `go.microsoft.com` now supports only TLS1.2 protocol.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
```

- `"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001`
- `"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001`

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#configuring-security-via-the-windows-registry)

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue and this solution work for me.
I add two DWORD 32 bits. I named them `SystemDefaultTlsVersions` and `SchUseStrongCrypto`. Then right click and modify. And I past `00000001` value with `hex` settings.

Comment: This worked to restore the VS 2013 license on my Win 10 dev PC.

Comment: Thankyou.  I knew it was something to do with TLS, but I kept focussing on win10 rather than this VS dependency.

Comment: worked with VS 2013 Community edition & windows 10. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a powershell script fixing it for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-tls-enforcement

Answer (score 0):

For those who ar running a 32-bit operating system (as was the case with me), the registry key you need to edit to fix this is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319
```

Then add the 32-bit DWORDs to this key as in the other answer:

```
SystemDefaultTlsVersions = 1
SchUseStrongCrypto = 1
```